# unity3d UnityScript to c# converting trouble?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm converting a UnityScript script to a c# script but i am stuck on this part. I'm trying to draw a line between

```
for (int i=0; i<path.Count; i++) {
    new Vector3 pos = path[i];
    if (i>0) {
        var prev=path[i-1].position;
        new Gizmos.DrawLine(prev,pos);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(pos,0.6f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should go there instead: http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html

Comment: just did thanks anny way ;)

Comment: Your comment is a big ambiguous - are you saying that you did it and it worked, or you looked there previously, so the comment was unhelpful?

Comment: i was posting it at unity3d while herve S answered. i just need to get past this part so i can continue making my game.